# How to extract Insights for a particular user in App Center/Hockey App

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, hockeyapp, visual-studio-app-center

I currently have a Xamanin Native mobile application and deployed in Hockey App. I have a new requirement to track user activities in the application. I can actually track a few overall details like the number of new users, crashes etc through Hockey App. But I would like to know per user analytics - like what the particular user is accessing, device that he/she is using, etc. Is there is a way to achieve this? Meanwhile, as HockeyApp is going to be migrated to App Center I would like to know if there are any features that are available in App Center already

Comment: Yes, you can, *but* it is not a free service, you can setup App Center to continuously export to Azure App Insights (and thus an Azure Subscription is required), review some of the docs here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-usage-flows

Comment: Hi Sushi, In the App Center I am not sure how would you configure the UserID. If a Web App, we can actually configure like the below link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-usage-send-user-context.

Answer (score 1):

I have used both App Center and Firebase for Analytics, and neither one of them supports the ability to drill down into a particular user. Firebase can at least see a "Stream View" of users in the past 30 minutes, but that's the best you will get.

This year App Center has released a few features that prevented me from using it for more than crash reports. To track what your users are doing in your app, import the App Center Analytics NuGet package (Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics).

Initialize the Analytics & Crashes SDK in your Start() method:

```
AppCenter.Start("{Your App Secret}", typeof(Analytics), typeof(Crashes));
```

Use the Analytics.TrackEvent method to then report what the user is doing in your app:

```
Analytics.TrackEvent("Video clicked");
```

Documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/xamarin

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/analytics/xamarin

To answer your HockeyApp question, move on from that platform onto App Center. Microsoft's migration of my apps from HockeyApp went on far too long and too slow to wait on Microsoft.